Understanding DMARC report - DKIM pass on SPF fail
I am looking for some help understanding a DMARC report for my email server. The xml content looks like the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>5064312124151702006</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1716940800</begin>
      <end>1717027199</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>example.com</domain>
    <adkim>s</adkim>
    <aspf>s</aspf>
    <p>reject</p>
    <sp>reject</sp>
    <pct>10</pct>
    <np>reject</np>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>209.85.220.69</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>example.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>mail</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>fail</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>198.51.100.56</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>example.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>mail</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>

From my understanding, this report indicates that there has been 2 IP addresses sending emails using my domain: 209.85.220.69 (Google's mail-sor-f69.google.com) and 198.51.100.56 (redacted for privacy). Out of these two IPs, they both had passing DKIM checks, while one of them had a failing SPF check. If I'm not misunderstanding how SPF works, this seems normal to me, since the IP address with the failed SPF check is not my server's IP address, and therefore, the email does not pass SPF. On receiving servers, such as Gmail, I get the following in the headers:
dkim=pass header.i=@example.com header.s=mail header.b=KBd35XCX;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@example.com designates 198.51.100.56 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@example.com;

This makes me believe that SPF is working correctly, and that DKIM is at least working correctly for my own domain. What I am having trouble understanding then is why would DKIM pass for that other IP address with the failed SPF? Perhaps I am misunderstanding how DKIM is meant to work, but from reading other responses and DMARC reports from other users here, they seem to be getting DKIM failures for senders not directly from their own domain. Is that not how it's meant to work? Some insight would be greatly appreciated!
As a side note, a couple of months ago I was constantly receiving a ton of incoming spam email coming from my own email address(typical email asking for crypto ransom). That made me realize I was being spoofed which led me to realize I had my email server(Postfix) configured incorrectly regarding the SPF checks. However, I changed the settings and all that spam email stopped coming. I have also used several testing services like dmarc-tester, emailspooftest, mxtoolbox, etc., and they have all reported good status for my email, though no explanation as to this part. The trusted hosts for OpenDKIM file only includes the loopback address of the server, and the signing table includes only *@example.com addresses.

The most likely scenario is that your message was automatically forwarded to another address and the receiving server tested the SPF against the forwarding server. This could, e.g., be someone forwarding messages from an old email account to a new one or a mailing list.
For these use cases, DMARC was designed to pass if either SPF or DKIM is passing and aligned. A DKIM signature survives the forwarding as long as the message (body or any of the signed headers) is not modified.
A fairly comprehensive article on the subject is "DMARC aggregate reports explained" by Freddie Leeman. It states the same:

This is mainly caused by servers forwarding your message. Since the message was initially DKIM signed and not changed during transit, DMARC passed, and the message was delivered (disposition none).

Furthermore, this is not a problem you would like to "solve". Adding the IP address to your SPF record would allow this server to send any messages in your name, not just the forwarded ones. Also, a decent forwarding service would also change the envelope sender a.k.a. Return-Path, in which case the SPF would not align anyway. Leeman continues:

Adding the source IP addresses to your SPF policy will not fix this SPF issue because the Return-Path of the messages will always cause alignment issues. However, if these messages are forwarded by a server you control, you could investigate whether or not the Return-Path can be changed to match the "Header from" domain.


Hi Esa, thank you for your response and article. That clears up the panorama! There is something I am not yet grasping: does each server decide whether to reject or forward an email based on DMARC and the policy set?
My server is a one user server(I am the only one using it), and I have only sent mails to one gmail address(mine). The failed SPF IP address is apparently Google's(according to an IP lookup site). So, could that mean Google internally forwarded my email to my Gmail inbox? None of my older reports have differing IPs, and my policy is set to p=reject; pct=10. Thanks again!

DMARC policies are not used for forwarding decisions per se. Instead, a forwarding service first receives the message, where checking DKIM/SPF/DMARC can be done if they are supported & configured. Only after that the message is handled by any internal rules for accepted messages (put into a mailbox, forwarded, content analyzed etc.). In the case of forwarding the server becomes a client (in terms of the SMTP protocol); the next hop handles it regardless of what has happened before.

That makes more sense now! Thank you Esa for the clarification! As for the WHOIS entry, I forgot to mention I modified the IPs prior to posting; I thought adding random IPs as opposed to the real ones just like using example.com as the domain, would make sense. My apologies for that! Do let me know if I should edit the post with the relevant one. The actual IP with the failing SPF but passing DKIM is 209.85.220.69, which seems to be Google's. Would that then mean that the statement of Google forwarding the mail(maybe to another of their own servers as the next hop(?)) make sense?

I see. You shouldn't be using someone else's IP addresses. I have modified your question so that the real IP address of Google is shown, and replaced your IP address with a special use IP address reserved for documentation (RFC 5735).

Noted for future Q's. Thanks. Still in doubt but marked as solved. Will look elsewhere for more info. Appreciate your time :)
